# Azure Devops - Terraform task fails with Error: Invalid backend configuration argument

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I am tying to run terraform on my azure Devops pipeline. I am using the terraform extension version 0.1.8 from the marketplace by MicrosoftDevLabs
My task looks as below :

```
task: TerraformTaskV1@0
displayName: 'Terraform - Init'
inputs:
provider: 'azurerm'
command: 'init'
commandOptions: '-input=false'
backendServiceArm: 'service-connection'
backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'Project-RG'
backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'projectsa'
backendAzureRmContainerName: 'tfstate'
backendAzureRmKey: 'terraform.tfstate'
workingDirectory: terraform
```

The command it tries to execute is

```
`/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/0.13.5/x64/terraform init -backend-config=storage_account_name=projectsa -backend-config=container_name=tfstate -backend-config=key=terraform.tfstate -backend-config=resource_group_name=Project-RG -backend-config=arm_subscription_id=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx -backend-config=arm_tenant_id=*** -backend-config=arm_client_id=*** -backend-config=arm_client_secret=***’
```

And the error message is:

```
Initializing the backend...  
Error: Invalid backend configuration argument
The backend configuration argument "storage_account_name" given on the command line is not expected for the selected backend type.   
Error: Invalid backend configuration argument  
The backend configuration argument "container_name" given on the command line is not expected for the selected backend type.   
Error: Invalid backend configuration argument  
The backend configuration argument "key" given on the command line is not expected for the selected backend type.
```

Comment: Can you paste the error message?

Comment: Hello, the error is as such : `Initializing the backend...

Error: Invalid backend configuration argument

The backend configuration argument "storage_account_name" given on the command
line is not expected for the selected backend type.


Error: Invalid backend configuration argument

The backend configuration argument "container_name" given on the command line
is not expected for the selected backend type.


Error: Invalid backend configuration argument

The backend configuration argument "key" given on the command line is not
expected for the selected backend type.
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it. The solution is slightly embarrassing. The.tf files backend was mentioned as local.  Which now makes sense as local backend does not support these parameters. Changing the backend to azure fixed it. Make sure you have the correct backend defined as the error does say the parameters for the backend are not supported.

Comment: Thank you , just did it now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, just for the record, I changed the backend to `azurerm` and it's fixed

Comment: Thanks for this. I made the same goofy mistake.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar error and found that using task TerraformTaskV2@2 in my pipeline yml as opposed to the older TerraformTaskV1@0 resolved the issue. This newer task also works with very a recent Terraform version like 1.1.4.

```
  # Install Terraform on Agent
  - task: TerraformInstaller@0
    displayName: 'install'
    inputs:
      terraformVersion: '1.1.4'

  # Initialize Terraform
  - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
    displayName: 'init'
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'init'
      backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'prodbackendstf'
      backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'productiontfstate'
      backendAzureRmContainerName: 'tfstate'
      backendAzureRmKey: 'tf.state'
      backendServiceArm: 'IaC SPn'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform'
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using terraform v1.1.3 and the TerraformTaskV1@0 azure pipeline task. I was getting the same issue, strange as the same azurerm block used to work when I was using 0.14.X. To fix I edited the backend block so it would use `access_key` blob storage key instead, then removed TerraformTaskV1@0, and instead initialised terraform using a cmd task as shown below:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 2.92"
    }
  }

  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name = "**terraformStorageAccount**"
    container_name       = "**terraformStateFileContainer**"
    key                  = "**terraformStateFile**"
    access_key           = "**storageKey**" #this is sensitive so should be retrieved from safe place via keyvault or dev ops pipeline variables
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}
```

I use this task to replace the pipeline variables with the ones in the tf files. You'll have to install this task btw:

```
- task: replacetokens@3
  displayName: Replace Variable Tokens
  inputs:
    rootDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    targetFiles: '**/*.tf'
    encoding: 'auto'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    tokenPrefix: '**'
    tokenSuffix: '**'
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: false
```

Once the variables are replaced use a cmd task to terraform init

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'terraform init'
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran this

```yaml
- task: TerraformInstaller@0
  inputs:
    terraformVersion: '0.13.5'
- task: TerraformTaskV1@0
  inputs:
    provider: 'azurerm'
    command: 'init'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/stackoverflow/74-terraform'
    backendServiceArm: 'rg-the-code-manual'
    backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'TheCodeManual'
    backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'thecodemanual'
    backendAzureRmContainerName: 'infra'
    backendAzureRmKey: 'tfstate-so-74'
    commandOptions: '-input=false'
```

and got it working

```
2020-12-04T10:06:25.4318809Z [command]/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/0.13.5/x64/terraform init -backend-config=storage_account_name=thecodemanual -backend-config=container_name=infra -backend-config=key=tfstate-so-74 -backend-config=resource_group_name=TheCodeManual -backend-config=arm_subscription_id=<subscriptionId> -backend-config=arm_tenant_id=*** -backend-config=arm_client_id=*** -backend-config=arm_client_secret=***
2020-12-04T10:06:25.4670082Z 
2020-12-04T10:06:25.4675423Z [0m[1mInitializing the backend...[0m
2020-12-04T10:06:25.4738557Z [0m[32m
2020-12-04T10:06:25.4740133Z Successfully configured the backend "azurerm"! Terraform will automatically
2020-12-04T10:06:25.4742265Z use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.[0m
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9242628Z [33m
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9244849Z [1m[33mWarning: [0m[0m[1m"arm_client_id": [DEPRECATED] `arm_client_id` has been replaced by `client_id`[0m
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9246980Z 
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9248608Z [0m[0m[0m
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9249659Z [33m
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9251909Z [1m[33mWarning: [0m[0m[1m"arm_client_secret": [DEPRECATED] `arm_client_secret` has been replaced by `client_secret`[0m
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9252897Z 
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9254321Z [0m[0m[0m
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9255028Z [33m
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9256913Z [1m[33mWarning: [0m[0m[1m"arm_tenant_id": [DEPRECATED] `arm_tenant_id` has been replaced by `tenant_id`[0m
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9261480Z 
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9262574Z [0m[0m[0m
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9263605Z [33m
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9264816Z [1m[33mWarning: [0m[0m[1m"arm_subscription_id": [DEPRECATED] `arm_subscription_id` has been replaced by `subscription_id`[0m
2020-12-04T10:06:25.9265629Z
```

With info about deprecation of settings, but this at the moment doesn't lead to a fail. For this there is already [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-extensions/issues/882) and PR on github.

Did you run `TerraformInstaller` before `TerraformTaskV1`?

Comment: Fixed it. The solution is slightly embarrassing. The.tf files backend was mentioned as local.  Which now makes sense as local backend does not support these parameters.